# How i Show specific data from database

Tags: php, sql

hey everyone i have database i want to show data from database for specific category
i want to show data of city for example if i want to show data about new york so data only shown releavent to new york not for other cities too

Comment: Use `SELECT` statement in your query and filter the desired data using `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data, the language you want your solution in and expected outcome, I am going to have to guess what you want, but as @OsamaIbrahim says, you appear to be looking at a simple [SELECT statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp) with a simple [WHERE clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp).  The column names and values probably won't match what you have, but it would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE city = 'New York City';
```

If this is way off, please edit your question and add sample data, the language you want your solution in (PHP or SQL) and expected outcome so I can edit my answer to fit.